# Method.invoke what parameter it can take?

Tags: java, reflection, constructor, parameter-passing, illegalargumentexception

I have the method name in string which has to be invoked dynamically.
Method name.invoke(object,parameters)
In the above format what should the object be?
Should it be always creater by createNewInstance method?
How can I use an already constructed object instead of it?

Comment: Java does not distinguish between objects based on how they were instantiated.  You may reflectively invoke a method on any object of suitable type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> what should the object be?

If the method is `static`, the `object` parameter should be `null`.

If the method is not `static`, the `object` parameter should be the object you want to call the method on, i.e. the object that will be the value of `this` inside the method.

> Should it be always creater by createNewInstance method?

No.

> How can I use an already constructed object instead of it?

Give the "already constructed object" as the `object` parameter value.

---

*Example*

Normally, you would call a method like this:

```
myObj.foo("bar");
```

To make the same call using reflection:

```
Method m = myObj.getClass().getMethod("foo", String.class);
m.invoke(myObj, "bar");
```